# Let $f$ and $g$ be the functions defined by f$(t)=2t^2$ and $g(t)=t^2+5t$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have solved the following:

$f′(t)=4x$

$g′(t)=2x+5$

To solve the next step:

Let $p(t)=2t^2(t^2+5t)$ and observe that $p(t)=f(t)⋅g(t)$. Rewrite the formula for p by distributing the $2t^2$ term. Then, compute p′(t) using the sum and constant multiple rules.

So, I've done the following, using the sum rule:

$2t^2(t^2+5t)$

=$2t^4+10t^3$

=$\frac{d}{dx}\left(2x^4\right)+\frac{d}{dx}\left(10x^3\right)$

=$8x^3+30x^2$

Would this be the right process? Or, would the sum and constant multiple rules be used together?

Comment: (i) You'd better sort out whether you want to use $t$ or $x$ as the variable. (ii) You seem to write that a function equals its derivative, which isn't what you mean: better clean that up too.

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your process is right, you need to clear up which variable you are using. Considering the function is in terms of $t$, you would have to differentiate in terms of $t$. Therefore, the derivatives are $f'(t)=4t$ and $g'(t)=2x+5$. Then distributing the $2t^2$ in the $p(t)$ function, you have correctly found the derivative with the rules:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)+g(x)]=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\frac{d}{dx}+g(x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}c\times{f(x)}=c\times\frac{d}{dx}f(x), c\in\mathbb{R}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$$

So in your third line, you take out the coefficient with the second rule, then differentiate with the third rule. You do this separately to both terms before using the first rule to add up the derivatives. Note that these rules only work if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable on $[a,b]$ (which they are for your case) and the variable is $t$ instead of $x$. Also, at the top, you need to write $\frac{d}{dx}[2t^4+10t^3]$ instead of $2t^4+10t^3$. Your final derivative should therefore be:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[2t^4+10t^3]$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}2t^4+\frac{d}{dt}10t^3$$

$$=2\frac{d}{dt}t^4+10\frac{d}{dt}t^3$$

$$=2(4t^3)+10(3t^2)$$

$$=8t^3+30t^2$$

Hope this helps!